# insert query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Any one help me to convert the below sql query to mysql query please?

```
INSERT INTO [FLOOR].[dbo].[ProjectEmployeeMapping]
           ([ProjectId]
           ,[EmployeeId])
    select distinct prj.ProjectId, emp.EmployeeId  from
Employees emp inner join FLOOR.dbo.EmployeeProject ep
on emp.EmployeeRefID = ep.[Resource ID]
inner join Projects prj on
ep.[Project ID] = prj.ProjectCode
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: the above is sql query, i need the equivalent mysql query. its not running. telling some syntax error

Comment: Of course. But where did you get stuck or do you think we do it for you? Which part do you have a question about it? Do you get an error message you don't understand?

Comment: What of this query causes an error in MySQL?

Comment: 22:32:55 INSERT INTO [FLOOR].[dbo].[ProjectEmployeeMapping]            ([ProjectId]            ,[EmployeeId])     select distinct prj.ProjectId, emp.EmployeeId  from [FLOOR].[dbo].[Employees] emp inner join [FLOOR].[dbo].[EmployeeProject] ep on emp.EmployeeRefID = ep.[Resource ID] inner join [cgiFLOOR].[dbo].[Projects] prj on ep.[Project ID] = prj.ProjectCode Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[FLOOR].[dbo].[ProjectEmployeeMapping]            ([ProjectId]            ,[E' at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't use three part naming, so you need to know the destination tables.

```
INSERT INTO ProjectEmployeeMapping(ProjectId, EmployeeId)
    select distinct prj.ProjectId, emp.EmployeeId
    from Employees emp inner join
         EmployeeProject ep
         on emp.EmployeeRefID = ep.`Resource ID` inner join
         Projects prj
         on ep.`Project ID` = prj.ProjectCode;
```

The major issue with this query is the use of square braces for escaping identifiers.  MySQL uses backticks.  It would be better to give the columns names that don't have spaces.